# Referencing variable value as a column for the rowSelection argument in the rxDataStepXdf function

Tags: r, revolution-r

I have assigned a variable to take the column name of the dataset, say:

```
column_name <- "run_type"
```

Using the `rxDataStepXdf` function, i would like to filter my dataset to select only rows where `run_type = "Prime"` :

```
rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath, outFile=outputXDFPath,rowSelection=(run_type=="Prime"))
```

However, instead of explicitly specifying the column to filter, I need to pass the variable column_name instead :

```
rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath,outFile=outputXDFPath,rowSelection=(column_name=="Prime"))
```

This does not work as I'm guessing the function searches for a column whose name is "column_name" instead. I've tried the following ways and all of them didn't work for me:

```
rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath,outFile=outputXDFPath,rowSelection=(quote(column_name)=="Prime"))

rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath,outFile=outputXDFPath,rowSelection=(get("column_name")=="Prime"))

rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath,outFile=outputXDFPath,rowSelection=(eval(column_name)=="Prime"))

rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath,outFile=outputXDFPath,rowSelection=(eval(parse(text="column_name"))=="PRIME"))
```

How do I pass the value of column_name into the rowSelection argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your expression outside of the call to `rxDataStep` which makes it a bit easier to read. Then, one option is to use `parse` as you had with a bit of a change to the syntax you had.

```
rowExpr <- parse(text=paste(column_name,"=='PRIME'"))
rxDataStepXdf(inFile=datasetXDFPath, outFile=outputXDFPath, rowSelection= rowExpr)
```

Another option is to use `transformFunc` and pass the `column_name` as a `transfFormObject`.

```
rowXform <- function(dataList) {
  dataList$.rxRowSelection <- dataList[[selCol]] == 'PRIME'
  return(dataList)
}
rxDataStep(inFile=datasetXDFPath, outFile=outputXDFPath, 
           transformObject = list(selCol = column_name))
```